# How to find the most probable decay product energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Let there be some energy spectrum for some product particle x emitted in a decay:
$$\frac {d\Gamma} {dE_x} = f(E_x)$$
where $E_x$ is the energy of particles x. To find the most probably energy for particles x, why do we maximize $f$ with respect to $E_x$? Shouldn't we maximize $\Gamma$ with respect to $E_x$? In other words, isn't the most probable energy for particles x the energy at which the decay rate $\Gamma$ is maximal? Why should it be where the rate of change of the decay rate is maximal?

Comment: How are you defining $\Gamma(E_x)$?

Comment: I don't really know. Initially I thought to find the rate at which particles of a certain energy are detected but that seems hard to do in real life. Actually, with regards to that, I'm not so sure how to construct $\frac {d\Gamma} {dE_x}$ either. But at any rate, I'm confused as to why the most probably energy wouldn't be at where $\frac {d\Gamma} {dE_x}$ is zero.